# Updating rows based on previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table - it is a temporary table -:

| ID | Name | Start | End | Job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 2011 | 2012 | Plumber |
| 1 | Joe | 2012 | 2014 | Electrician |
| 1 | Joe | 2014 | 2016 | Administrator |
| 2 | Marta | 2005 | 2015 | Secretary |
| 2 | Marta | 2015 | 2016 | Firefighter |
| 2 | Marta | 2016 | 2021 | Driver |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2010 | 2012 | NULL |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2012 | 2015 | Chef |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2015 | 2017 | Painter |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2017 | 2020 | Administrator |

What I would like to achive the have customized column where  I can see the co-workers previous job. This is the expected result:

| ID | Name | Start | End | Job | Job from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 2011 | 2012 | Plumber | NULL |
| 1 | Joe | 2012 | 2014 | Electrician | Plumber |
| 1 | Joe | 2014 | 2016 | Administrator | Electrician |
| 2 | Marta | 2005 | 2015 | Secretary | NULL |
| 2 | Marta | 2015 | 2016 | Firefighter | Secretary |
| 2 | Marta | 2016 | 2021 | Driver | Firefighter |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2010 | 2012 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2012 | 2015 | Chef | NULL |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2015 | 2017 | Painter | Chef |
| 3 | Elizabeth | 2017 | 2020 | Administrator | Painter |

Here is my attempt, but it is now working:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [ID], [Job], [Start],[End], [Job from],
           LAG([Job from]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID,Start,End 
           ORDER BY [ID],[Start],[End]  ASC) AS NextStatus
    FROM #Main)
UPDATE CTE
 SET [Job from] = NextStatus;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be partitioning by `Start` and `End` that is limiting your partition to a single row each time. Instead try: `LAG([Job]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Start], [End])`. Also, it is a good idea to avoid special characters (e.g. spaces) or reserved words (e.g. End) in your object names. As another aside *"Not working"* is not a very helpful problem description. If it is throwing an error, tell us what the error is. if it is returning unexpected results, show us the unexpected results. Help us to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, so the main issue is that the field what I have been created for that [Job from] is not populating.

Comment: @SalmanA what is missing from the date designator, that it has month attributes. So, no... they can't be overlaping.